# Prove this inequality $x^x\cdot y^y\cdot z^z\ge\frac{27}{(6-x-y-z)^3}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z\in (0.1)$ show that
$$x^x\cdot y^y\cdot z^z\ge\dfrac{27}{(6-x-y-z)^3}\tag{1}$$
or
$$x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}+z\ln{z}+3\ln{(6-x-y-z)}\ge 3\ln{3}$$

since
$f(x)=\ln{x}$,By Jenson inequality
$$x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}+z\ln{z}\le (x+y+z)f\left(\dfrac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}\right)$$
Clear this idea is wrong

But I can't seem to find a way to show this inequality$(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jensen won't work here, since you want to decrease the LHS to give a stricter bound ("≥") but Jensen only gives a looser bound ("≤").

Instead, use a weighted GM-HM inequality:

$$ (x^x y^y z^z)^{1/(x+y+z)} \ge \frac{x+y+z}{\frac xx+\frac yy+\frac zz} = \frac{x+y+z}3 \iff x^x y^y z^z \ge \left(\frac{x+y+z}3\right)^{x+y+z} $$
This reduced to just showing
$$ \left( \frac s3\right)^s \ge \frac{27}{(6-s)^3} $$
for $s\in(0,3)$.